# Setting workbook with variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I am encountering a strange issue when I use variable names to define and set variables for workbooks. The user opens three workbooks (dashboard, source and target). In the dashboard workbook the user then inputs the names of the source and target workbooks - so for instance "source.xls" and "target.xlsm". These inputs are defined as ranged names called "FILE_SOURCE" and "FILE_TARGET".

As such, I use the range names to define my workbook variables as in the following:

```
Dim sourceModel, targetModel As String
sourceModel = wbMainDashboard.Range("FILE_SOURCE") 'Pull from dashboard input (works)
targetModel = wbMainDashboard.Range("FILE_TARGET") 'Pull from dashboard input (works)

'Source and target workbooks
Dim wbSource As Workbook: Set wbSource = Workbooks(sourceModel) 'Workbook already open (doesn't work)
Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = Workbooks(targetModel) 'Workbook already open (doesn't work)
```

This works perfectly fine when the source and target workbooks are both saved on the desktop but for some reason it doesn't work when they are saved on the drives on my computer. As such, I was thinking that I may have to specify the full path location of the source and target workbooks in order to define the wbSource and wbTarget variables?

In order to do this I tried to implement the following function which should return the file paths:

```
Public Function GetWorkbookReference(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook

Dim wbReturn As Workbook

Set wbReturn = Workbooks(Dir$(sFullName))
Set GetWorkbookReference = wbReturn

End Function
```

After which I wanted to call this function when defining the wbSource and wbTarget variables:

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook: Set wbSource = GetWorkbookReference(sourceModel) 'Workbook already open (doesn't work)
Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = GetWorkbookReference(targetModel) 'Workbook already open (doesn't work)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either. If anyone can assist in figuring out why either of these to alternatives doesn't work that would be very helpful. If you know of a third alternative that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: What for example is in `Range("FILE_SOURCE")`?

Comment: You are asking users to enter the names of workbooks into a spreadsheet.  This kind of request is not nice to the user.  What you should have is two buttons in your dashboard which link to the Application FIleOpen dialogs which allow the users to use the filepicker to select the relevant workbooks.  In that way you will avoid completely the issues you are currently facing and make your dashboard much easier for the users to use.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work if these workbooks are open, are you sure your variables match wb names? Did you consider `Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filepath)` if these are always the same, otherwise maybe let the user select these workbooks using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` ?